# How to change only the difference Concisely in FireStore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When updating FirebaseStorage, I make processing to change only by change.
Instead of sending the value of textField as it is, we create an optional variable called newOO separately, so that the value entered in newOO is changed, and nil is entered if it is not.

Here is the process of adding to the dictionary when there is a change in that variable (if it is not nil) and not adding it to the dictionary if there is no change (nil).

```
var newName: String? = "name"
var newAge: Int? = 20
var newID: String? = "123456789"

var dict = [String: Any]()

if let newName = newName {
    dict["newName"] = newName
}
if let newAge = newAge {
    dict["newAge"] = newAge
}
if let newID = newID {
    dict["newID"] = newID
}
```

However, the more items there are, the more descriptions there are.
Is there a way to write this process more concisely?

Comment: Not sure the question is clear, or what it has to do with Firestore. Let me say it back to make sure it's clear; when building a dictionary of key:value pairs, you only want to add key's for values that are not nil. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a problem with an application currently using Firebase, but Firebase does not matter if it is told, it is a problem of Dictionary. Yes. I only want to add key's for values that are not nil.
I am sorry for confusing questions.